# Removing horizontal scroll bar when there is zoom out done through transform scale

Tags: html, css, zooming

You can observe there is a scrollbar when you run the below code when the html is scale down to 50% and increased width to fit in the window. This is not hapenning in firefox and only in chrome.
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/qBJbLqp

The content DOM  can be changed and not in my control. Hiding the scroll bar using overflow-x:hidden can cause to hide if there is actual need for the scrollbar. This can happen if the content DOM exceeds 100% width;

```css
html {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: 200%;
  height: 50%;
}

.parent {

  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta fermentum leo ut rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras nibh augue, viverra ut purus id, aliquet hendrerit dui. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque suscipit feugiat neque, nec convallis felis viverra sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pulvinar pulvinar arcu id iaculis. Vestibulum
  ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec faucibus imperdiet leo, tincidunt consectetur ante. Donec accumsan mauris vitae velit lacinia molestie. Nunc quis porttitor odio. Aenean sit amet nisl sem. Etiam ultricies
  arcu ut orci condimentum tempus. Aliquam eget purus nulla. Nullam elementum neque ut elit consequat varius. Cras facilisis faucibus diam, ac venenatis augue porttitor laoreet. Donec tincidunt arcu vel porttitor consequat. Vestibulum molestie urna id
  ipsum molestie suscipit. Aenean id finibus ex, venenatis sagittis ipsum. Cras id nibh pretium, dictum justo vehicula, pellentesque nunc. In rutrum, tellus at posuere bibendum, eros sapien pellentesque nisi, eu blandit mi nisi a mi. Quisque vitae nunc
  sed quam varius tincidunt id eget libero. Nunc id risus eget nisi molestie fringilla sit amet eget elit. Duis nec dolor porta massa elementum finibus a et nunc. In a augue vitae orci tempor placerat. Suspendisse at tempor metus, pharetra sodales arcu.
  Cras placerat facilisis odio vitae condimentum. Aenean sodales dapibus fermentum. Donec sem sapien, finibus vel ultrices vitae, finibus fermentum velit. Fusce ante massa, pulvinar sed blandit tempus, rhoncus at justo. Fusce varius justo sed arcu malesuada,
  vitae aliquet felis gravida. Integer sit amet dolor vitae libero blandit hendrerit. Mauris rutrum erat nec molestie tincidunt. Sed libero diam, blandit eu nisl at, sollicitudin pellentesque nunc. Quisque ac laoreet nisi. Vestibulum eu posuere odio,
  iaculis scelerisque quam. Morbi facilisis tellus non pulvinar faucibus. Nulla fringilla, velit nec feugiat fringilla, turpis sem pretium lectus, nec auctor arcu nisl ut felis. Cras eleifend efficitur commodo. In elit est, semper ut mauris non, dignissim
  suscipit ex. Sed sodales ac ex a consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur eget diam at nisl luctus tempus pellentesque ut nulla.


</div>
```

Comment: why do you set `height: 100px;`

Comment: Removed height it is set arbitrarily

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jahangeer. Overflow-x is a good option. Although, I wanted to try it without using an overflow property. You will need to set scaling on the .parent div and then set the body element to a flex object while using positioning. Note that Firefox needs the flex object to display properly and Chrome doesn't (see fiddle).

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: 200%;
}
.parent::after {
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta fermentum leo ut rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras nibh augue, viverra ut purus id, aliquet hendrerit dui. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque suscipit feugiat neque, nec convallis felis viverra sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pulvinar pulvinar arcu id iaculis. Vestibulum
  ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec faucibus imperdiet leo, tincidunt consectetur ante. Donec accumsan mauris vitae velit lacinia molestie. Nunc quis porttitor odio. Aenean sit amet nisl sem. Etiam ultricies
  arcu ut orci condimentum tempus. Aliquam eget purus nulla. Nullam elementum neque ut elit consequat varius. Cras facilisis faucibus diam, ac venenatis augue porttitor laoreet. Donec tincidunt arcu vel porttitor consequat. Vestibulum molestie urna id
  ipsum molestie suscipit. Aenean id finibus ex, venenatis sagittis ipsum. Cras id nibh pretium, dictum justo vehicula, pellentesque nunc. In rutrum, tellus at posuere bibendum, eros sapien pellentesque nisi, eu blandit mi nisi a mi. Quisque vitae nunc
  sed quam varius tincidunt id eget libero. Nunc id risus eget nisi molestie fringilla sit amet eget elit. Duis nec dolor porta massa elementum finibus a et nunc. In a augue vitae orci tempor placerat. Suspendisse at tempor metus, pharetra sodales arcu.
  Cras placerat facilisis odio vitae condimentum. Aenean sodales dapibus fermentum. Donec sem sapien, finibus vel ultrices vitae, finibus fermentum velit. Fusce ante massa, pulvinar sed blandit tempus, rhoncus at justo. Fusce varius justo sed arcu malesuada,
  vitae aliquet felis gravida. Integer sit amet dolor vitae libero blandit hendrerit. Mauris rutrum erat nec molestie tincidunt. Sed libero diam, blandit eu nisl at, sollicitudin pellentesque nunc. Quisque ac laoreet nisi. Vestibulum eu posuere odio,
  iaculis scelerisque quam. Morbi facilisis tellus non pulvinar faucibus. Nulla fringilla, velit nec feugiat fringilla, turpis sem pretium lectus, nec auctor arcu nisl ut felis. Cras eleifend efficitur commodo. In elit est, semper ut mauris non, dignissim
  suscipit ex. Sed sodales ac ex a consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur eget diam at nisl luctus tempus pellentesque ut nulla.
<br><br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta fermentum leo ut rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras nibh augue, viverra ut purus id, aliquet hendrerit dui. Class
  aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque suscipit feugiat neque, nec convallis felis viverra sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pulvinar pulvinar arcu id iaculis. Vestibulum
  ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec faucibus imperdiet leo, tincidunt consectetur ante. Donec accumsan mauris vitae velit lacinia molestie. Nunc quis porttitor odio. Aenean sit amet nisl sem. Etiam ultricies
  arcu ut orci condimentum tempus. Aliquam eget purus nulla. Nullam elementum neque ut elit consequat varius. Cras facilisis faucibus diam, ac venenatis augue porttitor laoreet. Donec tincidunt arcu vel porttitor consequat. Vestibulum molestie urna id
  ipsum molestie suscipit. Aenean id finibus ex, venenatis sagittis ipsum. Cras id nibh pretium, dictum justo vehicula, pellentesque nunc. In rutrum, tellus at posuere bibendum, eros sapien pellentesque nisi, eu blandit mi nisi a mi. Quisque vitae nunc
  sed quam varius tincidunt id eget libero. Nunc id risus eget nisi molestie fringilla sit amet eget elit. Duis nec dolor porta massa elementum finibus a et nunc. In a augue vitae orci tempor placerat. Suspendisse at tempor metus, pharetra sodales arcu.
  Cras placerat facilisis odio vitae condimentum. Aenean sodales dapibus fermentum. Donec sem sapien, finibus vel ultrices vitae, finibus fermentum velit. Fusce ante massa, pulvinar sed blandit tempus, rhoncus at justo. Fusce varius justo sed arcu malesuada,
  vitae aliquet felis gravida. Integer sit amet dolor vitae libero blandit hendrerit. Mauris rutrum erat nec molestie tincidunt. Sed libero diam, blandit eu nisl at, sollicitudin pellentesque nunc. Quisque ac laoreet nisi. Vestibulum eu posuere odio,
  iaculis scelerisque quam. Morbi facilisis tellus non pulvinar faucibus. Nulla fringilla, velit nec feugiat fringilla, turpis sem pretium lectus, nec auctor arcu nisl ut felis. Cras eleifend efficitur commodo. In elit est, semper ut mauris non, dignissim
  suscipit ex. Sed sodales ac ex a consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur eget diam at nisl luctus tempus pellentesque ut nulla.
</div>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pLhadzvr/

Comment: I am not able understand why does we need flex ?

Comment: Firefox displays empty space below the .parent div, essentially doubling the page height. Adding a flex object with a direction of column will prevent the extra white space at the bottom. Chrome renders it fine without flex, but it doesn't hurt to keep it in there.

Answer (score 0):

When using the CSS transform property on the html element, you can also add overflow: hidden to the html element to hide the scrollbar in Chrome:

---

```css
html {
transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 200%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.parent{
/*   overflow:auto; */
/*   height:100px; */
  font-size: 25px;
  background:yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porta fermentum leo ut rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras nibh augue, viverra ut purus id, aliquet hendrerit dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque suscipit feugiat neque, nec convallis felis viverra sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pulvinar pulvinar arcu id iaculis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec faucibus imperdiet leo, tincidunt consectetur ante. Donec accumsan mauris vitae velit lacinia molestie. Nunc quis porttitor odio.

Aenean sit amet nisl sem. Etiam ultricies arcu ut orci condimentum tempus. Aliquam eget purus nulla. Nullam elementum neque ut elit consequat varius. Cras facilisis faucibus diam, ac venenatis augue porttitor laoreet. Donec tincidunt arcu vel porttitor consequat. Vestibulum molestie urna id ipsum molestie suscipit.

Aenean id finibus ex, venenatis sagittis ipsum. Cras id nibh pretium, dictum justo vehicula, pellentesque nunc. In rutrum, tellus at posuere bibendum, eros sapien pellentesque nisi, eu blandit mi nisi a mi. Quisque vitae nunc sed quam varius tincidunt id eget libero. Nunc id risus eget nisi molestie fringilla sit amet eget elit. Duis nec dolor porta massa elementum finibus a et nunc. In a augue vitae orci tempor placerat. Suspendisse at tempor metus, pharetra sodales arcu. Cras placerat facilisis odio vitae condimentum. Aenean sodales dapibus fermentum.

Donec sem sapien, finibus vel ultrices vitae, finibus fermentum velit. Fusce ante massa, pulvinar sed blandit tempus, rhoncus at justo. Fusce varius justo sed arcu malesuada, vitae aliquet felis gravida. Integer sit amet dolor vitae libero blandit hendrerit. Mauris rutrum erat nec molestie tincidunt. Sed libero diam, blandit eu nisl at, sollicitudin pellentesque nunc. Quisque ac laoreet nisi. Vestibulum eu posuere odio, iaculis scelerisque quam.

Morbi facilisis tellus non pulvinar faucibus. Nulla fringilla, velit nec feugiat fringilla, turpis sem pretium lectus, nec auctor arcu nisl ut felis. Cras eleifend efficitur commodo. In elit est, semper ut mauris non, dignissim suscipit ex. Sed sodales ac ex a consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur eget diam at nisl luctus tempus pellentesque ut nulla.
  
  
</div>
```

---

---

This prevents the scrollbar from appearing even if the content overflows due to scaling. Make sure that all of your content fits within the scaled-down viewport, as this may hide any content that overflows the viewport.

Comment: Yeah I don't have control over the width of the content that is shown and as you mentioned it might hide the scrollbars in case where there are scrollbars.

Comment: sir, as shown in your snippet code the scroll bar is displayed on the main container(HTML element), for that hidden property has to be given there only.

Answer (score 0):

When zooming out using the transform: scale() CSS property, if the content of an element becomes too wide for its container, a horizontal scroll bar may appear. To prevent this, you can apply the following CSS to the container element:

```
enter code here.container {
```

overflow-x: hidden;
}

This will hide the horizontal scroll bar and prevent the user from scrolling horizontally when zoomed out.

Alternatively, you could also set the min-width property of the container element to a value that is equal to or greater than the width of the content after it has been zoomed out. This would ensure that the container element is always wide enough to fit the content, even when it is zoomed out. However, this approach may not be practical in all cases, as the width of the content may vary depending on the viewport size and other factors